# Is it possible to use Gatsby Head API with gatsby-plugin-mdx using the automatic page creation?

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin-mdx

I'm about to migrate from gatsby-plugin-react-helmet to the new Head API in my Gatsby project, as the Gatsby's support for React Helmet is apparently about to be deprecated in future. The site currently consists of a mix of static JSX pages and MDX via gatsby-plugin-mdx. The automatic page creation by placing the page components into `src/pages` is used, i.e. I'm not using the programmatic page creation via the createPages API or File System Route API. I prefer this approach for its clean directory structure and simplicity.

The problem is that if I have understood correctly, with Head API you add the document head to the page by exporting the head from page. With React Helmet, I could add the head in layout components, for example, but this is not possible with Head API. For JSX pages, it's not a problem to export from the page and I probably *could* do this in MDX files as well, but that wouldn't make any sense. I want to get the title data from the MDX frontmatter and do it automatically for MDX files. While I know that it's possible to do this using the createPages API or File System Route API and exporting Head from the page template, I still would like to stick with the automatic page creation if it's somehow possible. Has anyone using a similar approach yet managed to find a workaround for this? Or should I just reimplement the page creation using the alternative approaches?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the frontmatter in MDX: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/routing/mdx/#using-frontmatter-in-mdx

```
---
title: Building with Gatsby
author: Jay Gatsby
---

<h1>{props.pageContext.frontmatter.title}</h1>
<span>{props.pageContext.frontmatter.author}</span>
```

Then in your MDX you can do something like:

```
export const Head = () => <title>{props.pageContext.frontmatter.title}</title>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, the only viable options would be exporting from mdx files themselves or from a page template, if creating pages programmatically? Is there any alternatives for using the Head API, assuming that the React Helmet option will be deprecated in future?